# char pointer array assignment

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is a very quick question.
Why am I allowed to do this:

```
char* sentence[2] ={"blahblah","trololo"};
int main() {
  printf("%s",sentence[0]);
  printf("%s",sentence[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

but not this?:

```
 char* sentence[2];
 sentence[0] = "blahblah";
 sentence[1] = "trololo";
 int main() {
  printf("%s",sentence[0]);
  printf("%s",sentence[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider if you had multiple source files, each containing code *outside* of functions. When you compiled it together, when (and in what order) would you expect all of that code to execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not allowed to do the second part, because the assignment is outside of a function. When you move the assignment into `main()` (or another function), it will be valid

```
char* sentence[2];
int main() {
  sentence[0] = "blahblah";
  sentence[1] = "trololo";
  printf("%s",sentence[0]);
  printf("%s",sentence[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I allowed to do this:

```
char* sentence[2] ={"blahblah","trololo"};
```

Initialization is allowed for global variables.

> but not this?:

The statements

```
sentence[0] = "blahblah";
sentence[1] = "trololo";
```

makes no sense outside a function ( `main()` ). Move them inside the function and it will work.

Comment: I am not against downvoting (everytime). I welcome downvotes on my answers if that deserves but I am against the downvoting without any comment. Its really a bad practice.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry i didnt read in a correct way the question and i didnt see the function main()

the code works every time inside the functions. the functions have to be called!
main is called by the system. so this code is not attainable.

you can put out from the functions just global variable (example costant) or struct.